# CMD change file extension

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Hi i got a file 321983249423.0000 and another file with name 321983249423.0000.tif.

How can I change the tif extension to .0000 extension in order to replace the original file.

Thanks

Comment: I believe the `ren` command can help you there.

Comment: @Phixle  `Ren` alone will not work.  `Del` would be needed to remove the original file first, or `move` can be used by itself to replace the file.

Comment: The FOR command will allow you to split file name and extension so that you can manipulate them as much as you want. Example :          set file=filename.ext         for %W in (%file%) do ( echo %~nW )

Answer (score 1):

You can use this (supposed you are running the command in the directory that contains the files):

```
move /Y 321983249423.0000.tif 321983249423.0000
```

---

For more flexibility, you could also create a batch file named `repl.bat` with the following code:

```
@echo off
if "%~1"=="" (echo You specified no file to rename.) else (
echo Location is "%~dp1":
move /Y "%~f1" "%~n1" > nul 2>&1 && echo Renamed "%~nx1" to "%~n1". || echo Cannot find "%~nx1".)
pause
```

Call this batch file with the file (path) to rename as an argument (or just drag & drop the file to rename onto the batch file):

```
repl 321983249423.0000.tif
```

The script removes the (last) extension (`.tif` when `321983249423.0000.tif` is given) of the specified file and renames it accordingly; if another file with the new name already exists (`321983249423.0000`), it is overwritten without prompting. Replace `/Y` by `/-Y` at `move` command to force prompting.

Answer (score 0):

The script will be something like this:

```
IF EXIST D:\PATH\321983249423.0000 DEL /Q D:\PATH\321983249423.0000
IF EXIST D:\PATH\321983249423.tif REN D:\PATH\321983249423.tif 321983249423.0000
```

NOTE: REN is the same as RENAME.

Comment: Thanks @foxidrive ..  I reformatted my answer to fit the question.